# Weird HTTP header at Flickr

Tags: http-headers, flickr

I was, with no specific reason, exploring the HTTP headers sent by certain websites. At Flickr, a photograph file was sent using the following header:

```
X-Henrys-Special-Sauce: original spice
```

What does this mean at all? Just a easter egg thingy or Yahoo's kind of humour, or is it a term used in programming?

When refreshing the page, the header wasn't sent anymore...

Comment: It's just a joke header. It doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slashdot still has its `X-Bender` quote.  This is the last one i've got:

```
X-Bender:Crippling pain? That's not covered by my insurance fraud.
```

Comment: Oh, then I guess I just don't have this kind of humour really :)